# Android thread not stopping

Tags: java, android, multithreading

so im integrating a feature in my app, where the app can read analog signals from a microphone connected to an arduino via bluetooth. Now i want to show this analog signals in a certain textview and update them every second. I do this using a thread.

Now my Problem is: the thread starts properly and displays the corretct signals, but when i try to stop it with .interrupt() it just keeps going. Anybody an idea where my mistake could be?

So here is my code:

the function called in my thread:

```
 public void showTerminalOutput (TextView terminalOutput)
    {
        //Input stream ablesen auf dem seriellen Monitor und das Ganze abbilden auf Textview
        //input stream ablesen
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
            inputStream.skip(inputStream.available()); //Überspringt den InputStream der möglicheweise schon vorher da war

            //TODO: Die Größe der Forschleife muss abhängig vom Input Stream ermittelt werden, da ich jedoch noch nicht weiß wie das geht, benutze ich hier VORLÄUFIG eine statische Zahl
            String Ausgabe = new String();

            for (int i = 0; i<3; i++ )
            {
                byte b = (byte)inputStream.read();
                //print it out in the console
                System.out.println((char) b);
                //String konkattenieren
                String str = String.valueOf((char)b);
                System.out.println(str);


                Ausgabe = Ausgabe + str;


            }
            //String konkattenieren und im Terminal Ausgeben
            System.out.println("Die Ausgabe ist gespeichert als: " + Ausgabe);
            terminalOutput.setText(Ausgabe);


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("something went wrong @ Funktion Terminal Output");
        }

    }
```

the thread:

```
public Thread analogeAnzeige()
{
    return new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run(){

            while(!(t.isInterrupted())){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            showTerminalOutput(analog1);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    t.interrupt();
                }

            }
        }
    };
}
```

now in onCreate i just have another thread analog which i initialise as :

```
analog = analogeAnzeige();
```

Then i have to buttons Go and Stop.
At go onclick i do:

```
analog.start();
```

At stop onclick i do:

```
analog.interrupt();
```

anybody seeing my mistake?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In the Thread implementation what does `t` refer to? Why don't you just check on the current thread?

Comment: @bowmore oh man yeah okay there was my mistake, it works now. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

ok so im stupid and was referring to another thread "t" instead of the thread "analog". Take some breaks while coding, kids! ;)